# Phantom margin/padding on top of parent div

Tags: html, css, layout

Here's the link to the problem: [link](http://codepen.io/lucusp/pen/vONBOG?editors=110)

The `div`'s in question are the gray ones inside the green one. You'll notice that their width *will* fit inside of the parent (green). However, the `float: left` property on the child divs does nothing. Only, when adding `float: left` on the parent will it work.

When doing so it adds some phantom spacing on the top of the parent div vs the nav element.

```
.options {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: green;
  /* float property */
  float: left; /* this will put child divs side by side but add space on top */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not clearing your container element which contains the floated elements. A quick solution would be to add `overflow: hidden;` on your 2 containers (`.navbar-3`, `.options`).

The only problem when doing this, is that everything which goes outside the container element is not visible anymore.

Another solution would be to implement the `.clearfix` hack by adding the following styles:

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

On your container elements, you can now add the `clearfix` class.

Comment: ok, i'll give that a go. I tried that on `.options` with same results as `float: left`, but not on both.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Mike! Will accept as soon as time permits :).

Comment: well the `.clearfix` didn't work. I'm going to try again, though.

Comment: dang. hilarious...soo...i forgot to float left the `nav`. Once done all is well.

Comment: You still get the check :).